# Trying to write a method in Java that will search a database list and return a Customer object, given a customerID

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a customer manager application for a Java course. I have it separated as per the requirements into 3 packages. The first package has a class called Customer, which models a customer and it's instance variables, such as customerID. The second package is a customer database that includes an ArrayList. The third package is going to be a menu driven UI that will allow the user to choose between 4 options. Currently, I am stuck trying to write a method that will search through the list for a given customerID and return a Customer object.

In the customer database class, I am getting the customerID from the user within the method. Then, I am running a for loop that should traverse the method to see if the customerID is found. I am having issues on how to return a customer object if the id is a match.

```
public Customer searchCustomer(String customerID) {

     System.out.println("Enter customer ID you want to find:");
     customerID = scnr.next();
     Customer c;

     for (int i = 0, i < customerList.size(); i++ {
          c = customerList.get(i);
          if (customerList.get(i).equals(customerID) {
          String foundID = customerID;
          }
     }
}
```

I want to return Customer c at the end of the method, but cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Why you need to reassign variable customerId  customerID = scnr.next(); in this method?

Comment: I would recommend storing it in a Map instead of List, you would have key customerId and value Customer object. In that case searching would be  easy Customer customer = customersMap.get(customerId)

Comment: Here is similiar topic you may want to explore https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774374/arraylist-retrieve-object-by-id

Answer (score 0):

In the if statement one can just write `return c`. This will return the first Customer that matches. At the end of the method one can return null or throw an exception if the Customer wasn’t found.

Answer (score 0):

You compare Customer object with CustomerId.

Change code to

```
if (customerList.get(i).getId().equals(customerID) {
    return customerList.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few of the potential mistakes you're making are:

1. Passing in an parameter to your method that you're not using.  Either do the `Scanner` stuff outside of the method and then pass the ID to the method, or do the `Scanner` part in the method and have no parameters.  The former approach is generally the preferred one, though.
2. Comparing the customer to a String.  You need to compare the user-entered ID to the `Customer` object's ID field.  The String the user enters will *never* be equal to the entire `Customer` object.
3. You're not returning anything from the method.  Once you find the `Customer` you're looking for, you need a `return` statement.

Also, you can use Java's "enhanced for loop" to make the code a bit cleaner.  Here's some code that assumes that your `Customer` objects use a `String` as their ID, and have a `.getID()` method on them to get their ID.

Here's some code that needs to search for a customer. This can be in another method.

```
System.out.println("Enter customer ID you want to find: ");
customerID = scnr.next();
Customer customer = searchCustomer(customerID);
```

And here's the search method that loops through the customerList

```
public Customer searchCustomer(String customerID) {
    for(Customer customer : customerList) {
        if (customer.getId().equals(customerID) ) {
            return customer;
        }
    }
    return null;  // Or perhaps throw an exception.
}
```

Note that I'm making a lot of assumptions about how the other parts of your code that I haven't seen are structured, so you very probably will have to modify this code sample if you want to use it, but hopefully it puts you on the right track.

Comment: This seems very helpful! Now I just have to figure how to go about calling this in my application - this teacher is throwing some curveballs on this final project.